# Mongodb query use skip and limit function in first N documents

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Can we make query which enable us to use skip and limit in first N documents?

Ex :

Suppose there are nearly 500 documents in a collection called teachers.

I want a query which restrict me to read first 300 documents only.

If I use skip(300) in that query it should display null.

```
db.teachers.find().pretty()

{
  id : 1,
  name : "teach001"
},
{
  id : 2,
  name : "teach002"
},
{
  id : 3,
  name : "teach003"
},
{
  id : 4,
  name : "teach004"
},
{
  id : 5,
  name : "teach005"
},
{
  id : 6,
  name : "teach006"
},
{
  id : 7,
  name : "teach007"
},
{
  id : 8,
  name : "teach008"
},
{
  id : 9,
  name : "teach009"
},
{
  id : 10,
  name : "teach0010"
}



 db.teachers.find({some query here to restrict access first 5 documents only }).skip(5).limit(5).pretty()
```

Comment: Please add more details to your question with some sample data and query.

Comment: I think you'd need to pre-process your query's skip and limit parameters in code to enforce whatever rules you want.

Answer (score 0):

## Aggregation

I don't think there is a way to do exactly what you are requesting.  If you are open to using the [aggregation framework](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/), it can be accomplished easily.

```
db.teachers.aggregate([{$limit: 5}, {$skip: 5}])
```

---

## View

If you are open to creating a [view](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/views/), you could even create a view that enforces the limit

```
db.createView('limitedTeachers', 'teachers', [{$limit: 5}])
```

Then you can use find on the view:

```
db.limitedTeachers.find({}).skip(5)
```

---

## Two finds

If you cannot use aggregation, you have the option of using 2 finds in your query.  First, find the n number of Object IDs. Then, limit your second query to only those Object IDs.

```
var ids = [];
db.teachers.find({}, {_id: 1}).limit(5).forEach(function(doc){
    ids.push(doc._id);
});

db.teachers.find({ _id: {$in: ids} }).skip(5)
```

Or as the same type of query but closer to the format you had in your question

```
db.teachers.find({$or: db.teachers.find({}, {_id: 1}).limit(5).toArray()}).skip(5)
```